# mysql: Updating characters in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have table, and it looks something like this:

```
MerchantName
-----------
El Restaurante
The Restaurant
Il RDÃ¶torante
```

The thing is, I know I can do:

```
update table
set merchantName = 'Il Ristorante'
where merchantName like 'Il%'
```

but what if there's more like this, and with different names? I'm looking for a full solution, something like this:

```
update table
set Ã¶ = 'isto'
wherever these characters exist in the table
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks very much

Comment: Interestingly, the chars `Ã¶` which are the Unicode code points [`U+00C3`](https://codepoints.net/U+00C3) and [`U+00B6`](https://codepoints.net/U+00B6), looks like a misinterpretation of the UTF-8 sequence `C3 B6` which is the Unicode character `U+00F6`. The octet `F6` in the [ISO-8859-5](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-5.TXT) encoding corresponds to the Unicode character [`U+0456`](https://codepoints.net/U+0456) (CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ... **I**). This doesn't explain the `D` and the missing `s`. I can't help wonder how you ended up with _those_ characters in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET MerchantName = REPLACE(MerchantName, N'Ã¶', 'isto');
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/331037/1)

Comment: hmm interesting, but what does the N' achieve here?

Comment: It is used to qualify `nvarchar` literals. Have a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-national.html)

Comment: Hey thanks so much. it worked! learning something new every day :)